# typeorm query in object list

Tags: sql, sqlite, typeorm

I have an entity `House` with this column:

```
@ManyToMany(type => Person, Persons => Persons.Houses)
persons: Persons[];
```

And now i want to get all Houses that connected to a `person.id`:

```
this.houseRepository.find({
    where: {
        Persons: { ?? } // Here I cant do 'Persons: { id: idToFind }' 
    }
})
```

How can I query for this?

Answer (score 0):

try this

> query.leftJoinAndSelect('houses.persons', 'persons')
> .where("persons.id = :personId", {personId: 1 }).getMany();